# Mapping single MC Connect API User with multiple SF System Users

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

We have the following setup currently:

- 3 BUs are connected to the same SF orgs.
- Each BU has a different SF system user that used for connecting to that org (in order to use different filters for the synchronized DEs).
- There is 1 MC API User for that org which is currently not mapped to any of the SF system users.

What we would like to know if it's possible in each BU to map the same MC API User separately for each SF system users (that belong to the same SF org)?

i.e:

BU 1: MC API USER A <> SF User 1

BU 2: MC API USER A <> SF User 2

BU 3: MC API USER A <> SF User 3

Will that configuration is possible? Is the mapping config is separated for each BU?

Another related question: what are the implications in case the SF system user is not mapped to the MC API user? In the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_marketing_cloud_api_user.htm&type=5) it is mentioned this affect core system communication. Since the connection between those BUs and the SF org seems to work just fine right now (without mapping the users) we can't understand how we are impacted by this missing configuration at the moment.

Many Thanks,

Barak

Comment: Are you using Scope by User? Are you using SF Data Entry sources in Journey Builder? Have you already started synching data in Contact Builder?

Comment: We are not using scope by user. We have already started syncing data in contact builder and using sf entry source in journey builder. Right now we aren't affected by not mapping the mc api user to the sf system user. That's is the reason for the last question regarding what are the implications for not mapping those users. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition Account-Level / user-Level Connection**

In your current setup, you have completed Account-Level Connection via the API User / System User pair, so you see most things working just fine.
You have not established User-Level Connection for the API user / System User pair. If you have no problem, I would say there is no need to do anything.
Nothing (except maybe missing licenses) stops you from establishing User-level connections for other users in your system when necessary.

**Effects of not integrating users**

Everything that requires a user-level connection (i.e. a context of "who is executing something") is not possible without mapping users. This would include also scope by user, which is not your usecase.

other examples:
e.g. unmapped users will not have access to the "Salesforce Email Send" activity in Automation studio. If you login as your MC API user, you should not see this activity type in Automation Studio.
Bit of a rare case but that's one visible difference.
This likely also affects Triggered Sends from Sales Cloud, but I haven't tested this. With Journey Builder being what it is, this has become pretty rare in my experience anyways.

**Connecting several users in one org to the same MC API User**

As for your intended configuration - not possible as per the documentation:

"You **can’t** map a single Marketing Cloud user to more than one Sales or Service Cloud user within one org."

...and also phrases it the other way around:

"You **can** map a single Marketing Cloud user to multiple Sales or Service Cloud users **if the Sales or Service Cloud users are in different orgs** and the Marketing Cloud user has access to the connected business units."

highlights by me.
source:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed extensive answer. 1 question regarding the possibility of mapping 1 mc user to multiple sf users within the same org - perhaps this explanantion in the documentation refers to the scenario of mapping the mc user from the same BU? Beacuse right now we can see that each BU is completely independent with regard to mapping users in the setup. For example: user mc A was already mapped to a sf user in BU #1. However when we switch to BU #2 the settings show is not mapped at all (not intergated). So perhaps it's possbile to acheive this while using multiple BUs? Thanks

Comment: An addition to my last comment: what I'm asking is with regarding to the chart in the documentaion you sent is - wheather U1 of BU2 can be mapped to UB. I don't see any reference to this case in the documentaion. Thanks again

Comment: reply to comment 1: I do not think so. The headline for the docs is multi-org configuration, so the basic assumption behind the entire article is that there are multiple BUs. The scenario you mentioned in your comment is also referenced in the article in the second to last bullet point: "You can map a Marketing Cloud user to the same Sales or Service Cloud user if the Marketing Cloud user can access multiple connected business units". -> the word "can" implying that NOT mapping is completely valid and does not counteract the other points.

Comment: as for comment 2: those graphics are absolutely terrible unfortunately. If you are  referring to the second chart, then I think: Connecting BU2 User "U1" to "UB" is the same idea as: Connecting BU1 User "U1" to "UC". And that is referenced. It's labeled connection "3", and the red line (as I judge from the text) indicates it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. This explanation has been really helpful.