# Difference between MC Connect in SF, Salesforce Integration Tab and Salesforce.com Status in Email Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, email-studio, sfmc-business-unit

What exactly is the difference between MC Connect in SF, Salesforce Integration Tab, and Salesforce.com Status in Email Studio?

I have some basic scenarios like the below:

**Scenario 1.** What will happen if I did not connect SF User to Marketing Cloud User in Salesforce CRM.

[image]

**Scenario 2.** What will happen if I connect SF User to Marketing Cloud User in Salesforce CRM But did not connect salesforce org in salesforce integration Tab in Marketing Cloud?

Like the Below image, I have connected one SF org. But What happens I didn't connect SF org.

[image]

**Scenario 3.** What will happen if I connect SF User to Marketing Cloud User in Salesforce CRM and also connect salesforce org in salesforce integration Tab in SFMC But not Integrate Salesforce.com Status?

What will be the impact on the specific user if a user is not integrated **Salesforce.com Status**?

[image]

Comment: This is a different question. Here I am asking about what will be impact if I will use or not use these functionality.

Comment: Hi @Rahul I think I answered your questions 1 and 3 here. search term was "account-level connection  user-level connection marketing cloud connect". these are the terms dropped in the documentation about this.  Scenario 2 is just a side effect of account-level connection, and that is non-optional. You HAVE to establish that first. So answer is simple: Scenario 2 does not happen.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318955/mapping-single-mc-connect-api-user-with-multiple-sf-system-users

Comment: Hi @jonas Lamberty,
I have completed Account-Level Connection via the API User / System User pair, and all things are working just fine. Now I have also established a User-Level Connection for the My API user. (Email =>  click Admin tab =>  click My Users =>  select the API User => click on Edit => click Integrate Link => Salesforce.com field => provide the SFDC User Name => click Save.)
On the SF side, I am able to see tracking info, and all other things regarding an email in the email send tab.

Comment: After that i have removed a User-Level Connection for the My API user. (Email =>  click Admin tab =>  click My Users =>  select the API User => click on Edit => click Integrate Link => Salesforce.com field => remove SFDC User Name => click Save.)And again I have sent an email from sf. Still I am able to see tracking info, and all other things regarding an email in the email send tab. 
So basically I want to understand what would be the impact if I didn't establish a User-Level Connection for the My API user.

Comment: please read the other post, section "Effects of not integrating users" - they are sparse, but they are there.